# Reusing tilemap segments

Tags: unity, 2d, tilemap, asset-workflow

I'm wondering how I can incorporate reusable tilemap segments in my workflow.

For example: I construct a room out of my tile palette, and I want to reuse this room in multiple places.

Is there some way to "prefab" a section of a tilemap? I haven't found such a thing.

Or perhaps I should just prefab the whole tilemap, and use multiple tilemap objects within one grid? Won't that introduce significant overhead?

What if I want to prefab a section of a tilemap with some additional, non-tilemap objects?

Comment: "Won't that introduce significant overhead" sounds like a question you can answer for yourself by trying it and profiling it.

Comment: True, but I'm asking what is the "best practice" way. Performance is just one aspect of it.